# Tortoise SVN commit query

Tags: tortoisesvn, commit

I am new to tortoise SVN and I did SVN commit for multiple files related to each other seperately. This has created a separate revision number for each file. How can I correct this? Ideally I would want all the files to have same revision number.

Appreciate any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use re-basing.

Move your original branch first:

```
AT_root=/Abhishek_Tiwaris_repository_root
svn mv $AT_root/Abhishek_Tiwaris_branch $AT_root/Abhishek_Tiwaris_branch-old
svn copy $AT_root/trunk $AT_root/Abhishek_Tiwaris_branch
svn up
```

Rebase merge.

```
svn merge $AT_root/Abhishek_Tiwaris_branch-old
svn commit
```

Remove the old branch

```
svn delete $AT_root/Abhishek_Tiwaris_branch-old
```

Check the log

```
svn log -vg --stop-on-copy
```